# Bullet not colliding with either plane or drone

Tags: collision-detection, godot

i made a godot game in which theres a player and a drone, I got the shooting to work but when i tried to make it so that the bullet attacks the drone/player, it wasnt working properly. Basically i made a area2d in the bullet and if a body enters it, i damage the body (player/drone). or if the body is a wall then i destroy the bullet. When i tried debugging body.name, all i got was 'Wall' in the console.
heres the code for the bullet

```
extends Node2D

var angle = 0
var speed = 0

func set_bullet_settings(new_angle, new_speed, pos, amountoffset):
    angle = new_angle
    speed = new_speed
    $BulletSprite.rotation_degrees = new_angle  
    $BulletSprite.position = pos
    
    $BulletSprite.position.x += cos(deg_to_rad(-angle)) * amountoffset
    $BulletSprite.position.y -= sin(deg_to_rad(-angle)) * amountoffset
    $AttackArea.position.x += cos(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90)) * amountoffset
    $AttackArea.position.y -= sin(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90)) * amountoffset

func update():
    $BulletSprite.position.x += cos(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90)) * speed
    $BulletSprite.position.y -= sin(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90)) * speed
    $AttackArea.position.x += cos(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90)) * speed
    $AttackArea.position.y -= sin(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90)) * speed


func _on_attack_area_body_entered(body):
    print(body.name)
    if body.name == 'Walls':
        queue_free()
```

code for player

```
extends CharacterBody2D

const speed = 5
const fast_speed = 7
const shoot_speed = 0.3
const bullet_speed = 50

var win_mode = 'fullscreen'
var bullets_shooten = []
var bullet_scene = preload('res://scenes/bullet/bullet.tscn')
var angle = 180
var can_shoot = true

func isnt_fast():
    return not Input.is_action_pressed("walk faster")

func _ready():
    $BulletTimer.wait_time = shoot_speed
    $BulletTimer.connect('timeout', set_can_shoot)
    
    DisplayServer.mouse_set_mode(DisplayServer.MOUSE_MODE_HIDDEN)

func set_angle_to_mousepos():
    var direction = (get_global_mouse_position() - self.global_position).normalized()
    angle = int(rad_to_deg(atan2(direction.y, direction.x))) + 90

func set_can_shoot():
    can_shoot = true

func move(amount):
    position.x += amount * cos(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90))
    position.y -= amount * sin(deg_to_rad(-angle + 90))

func shoot():
    var bullet = bullet_scene.instantiate()
    bullet.set_bullet_settings(angle, bullet_speed, position, randi_range(0,16))
    bullets_shooten.append(bullet)
    $'..'.add_child(bullet)
    can_shoot = false
    $BulletTimer.start()

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move forward"):
        move(speed  if isnt_fast() else fast_speed)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move backward"):
        move(-speed if isnt_fast() else -fast_speed)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot") and can_shoot:
        shoot()

    move_and_slide()

func enumerate(iterable):
    var index = 0
    var result = []

    for item in iterable:
        result.append([index, item])
        index += 1

    return result

func removeNullItems(inputArray: Array) -> Array:
    var newArray := []

    for item in inputArray:
        if item != null:
            newArray.append(item)

    return newArray

func _process(delta):
    set_angle_to_mousepos()
    angle = (angle + 360) % 360
    $Sprite.rotation_degrees = angle - 5
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed('fullscreen toggle'):
        if win_mode == 'fullscreen':
            DisplayServer.window_set_mode(DisplayServer.WINDOW_MODE_FULLSCREEN)
            win_mode = 'not fullscreen'
        else:
            DisplayServer.window_set_mode(DisplayServer.WINDOW_MODE_WINDOWED)
            win_mode = 'fullscreen'

    bullets_shooten = removeNullItems(bullets_shooten)


    for bullet in bullets_shooten:
        bullet.update()
```

code for drone

````
extends CharacterBody2D

const accuracy = 30

var can_shoot: bool = true
var bullet_scene = preload('res://scenes/bullet/bullet.tscn')
var shoot_speed = 0.7
var bullet_speed = 35
var bullets_shooten = []
var player_in_range = false

func _ready():
    $BulletTimer.wait_time = shoot_speed
    $BulletTimer.connect('timeout', set_can_shoot)

func set_can_shoot():
    can_shoot = true

func shoot(playerpos):
    var bullet = bullet_scene.instantiate()
    bullet.set_bullet_settings(rotation_degrees, bullet_speed, position, randi_range(0,accuracy))
    bullets_shooten.append(bullet)
    $'..'.add_child(bullet)
    can_shoot = false
    $BulletTimer.start()

func look_at_player(player_pos):
    look_at(player_pos)
    rotation_degrees += 90

func removeNullItems(inputArray: Array) -> Array:
    var newArray := []

    for item in inputArray:
        if item != null:
            newArray.append(item)

    return newArray

func update(player_pos):
    look_at_player(player_pos)
    if player_in_range and can_shoot:
        shoot(player_pos)

    bullets_shooten = removeNullItems(bullets_shooten)
    
    for bullet in bullets_shooten:
        bullet.update()





func _on_attack_range_body_entered(body):
    if body.name == 'Player':
        player_in_range = true

func _on_attack_range_body_exited(body):
    if body.name == 'Player':
        player_in_range = false


```
````

Comment: Not really a Godot user, but where exactly do you handle colliision of your bullet with either player or drone? All you have is one `body.name == 'Walls'`.

Comment: actually, i deleted that because i was debugging. The problem is that theres only 'Walls' showing in the console so that means for some reason the bullet isnt colliding with the drone/player

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to see in the code...

What I can give you is a short list of things to check to debug this:

- Make sure your `Area2D` and `CharacterBody2D` have their colliders (with their shape, and not disabled). Double check by setting "Visible Collision Objects" in the debug menu, which will show the colliders when the game is running. *This will also reveal if the colliders are positioned or moving in an unexpected way.*
- Make sure the collision layer and mask of the `Area2D` and `CharacterBody2D` overlap, otherwise, Godot won't even check for a collision between them.
- Make sure the `body_entered` signal is connected correctly. *I'm guessing it is connected since you say you got the output from `print`.* I presume you are connecting it from the editor (since the connection is not being made in the code you shared), in which case you should see in Godot text editor a green icon next to the method connected to the signal, and clicking it should show you what is connected.